# Calculate ratio (starting value of year/ending value of previous year) in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

As a plausibility check for yearly reports which are send in, I want to make sure that the stating value of a year is correct based on the ending value as submitted in the previous year. With this Multi-index dataframe I try to explain my problem:

```
import random
col3=[0,0,0,0,2,4,6,0,0,0,100,200,300,400]
col4=[0,0,0,0,4,6,8,0,0,0,200,900,400, 500]

d = {'Unit': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6], 
 'Year': [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017], 'col3' : col3, 'col4' : col4 }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.groupby(['Unit', 'Year']).sum()
```

What I want to do is create an additional column with the ratios. So for example: Unit 2 year 2016 col3/ Unit 2 year 2015 col 4 = 4/4 = 1. My next step would be to see if the ratio's are 1. I put one example in this dataframe where the ratio would not be one. That is in principle my interest case and i want to identify that datapoint.

One of the issue I have is that there are a lot of zero's in my dataframe.

Thank you for any input!

Jen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can apply a function on groupby:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Unit', 'Year']).sum()

new_df['mask'] = (new_df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
                  .apply(lambda x: x.col3/x.col4.shift())
                 )
```

Then your `new_df` looks like this:

```
           col3  col4      mask
Unit Year                      
1    2014     0     0       NaN
     2015     0     0       NaN
     2016     0     0       NaN
     2017     0     0       NaN
2    2015     2     4       NaN
     2016     4     6  1.000000
     2017     6     8  1.000000
3    2017     0     0       NaN
4    2014     0     0       NaN
5    2015     0     0       NaN
6    2014   100   200       NaN
     2015   200   900  1.000000
     2016   300   400  0.333333
     2017   400   500  1.000000
```

And you can `fillna` or filter those not equal to 1 as wished.